# How to change the scroll bar in the outliner section

Tags: interface

is there an option for the scroll bar in the outliner to be changed from the default grey to any other colour?

[image]

Comment: I believe you can only change it globally via Edit > Preferences > Themes tab > Scroll Bar. I think it's the 'Item' colour that you need to change.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was so confused which one to change afraid if I tamper with the colours I might ruin the UI, but this was it. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. In fact it's mentioned by Pablo in the latest [Blender Today LIVE video](https://youtu.be/_GaGYZS9zk4?t=471) about upcoming changes in the next Blender version.